# Creating a background color "ping" using only CSS3

Tags: css

I want to create a simple "ping" feature when an event happens on a div. For example, if the user clicks a div, I want the div to quickly change background color and then slowly transition back to the original color. I would like to do this purely with CSS3 if possible.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Might be able to have a gradient color and then slide it's position in the background.

Comment: Why down voted?? Yes I tried some things in JSFiddle but I could not get it to do what I wanted. I figured this is a fairly simple feature

Comment: @MattHintzke Probably downvoted because you have given no code and no example code of what you've tried. But I can go ahead and tell that onclick events are JavaScript territory. CSS is for styling, not interaction.

Comment: Well my attempts did not help at all so I figured they were useless.. fine I will add code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a trick with the `transition` property, and the pseudo class `:active` that will be triggered on click.

On the `:active` pseudo, set the transition to `0s`, so it will instantly change the color. Then, when it is not triggered anymore the default `transition: 1s /*or whatever speed*/` will slowly get it back to its original color.

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: silver;
    transition: 1s;
}

div:active {
    background: yellow;
    transition: 0s;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1vgef44t/

Comment: Actually, this works for clicking, but what if I want to activate the "ping" using another event?

Comment: As pointed by @TylerH on comments, css is not for events handling. There are few events you can set with css only, like `:hover`, `:active`... Anything else, you will have to handle through Javascript. On this case, you would have to use a css class to the coloring, changing, for example, `div:active `{` to `div.pingclass {`, and then toogle this class on/off using Javascript and you get the same result...

Comment: I tried toggling the class like you said before, but the `transition` never seems to take place. It just changes the background instantaneously

Comment: You must add the class, and instantly remove it... Just like a click works (mouse down / mouse up)!

Comment: Thats exactly what I did.. http://jsfiddle.net/1vgef44t/1/  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I was able to get it working by adding a very small timeout before `removeClass` is called.. but that just feels weird

Comment: Yes. It's needed because the browser renders the css by batch execution... setTimeout is executed asyncronously, so it gives the browser time to render the first instruction, and then the last one...